# rpm post install script failing when using system() API

Tags: linux, ld, rpm, rpmbuild

RPM post install script is failed when issued in the system call.  We do not see installation issues when post script is not mention in the spec file.

***.spec.in**

%post

sfile=/etc/ld.so.conf

if ! grep '^/usr/lib' $sfile > /dev/null 2>&1; then

  printf "%s\n" "/usr/lib" >> $sfile;

fi

The post script looks simple.

Preparing packages for installation...
readline-4.2-4
error: execution of %post scriptlet from readline-4.2-4 failed, exit status 255

Could you please help us here ?

```
ret = system("/bin/rpm -ivU --nodeps --force --root /mnt /tmp/readline-4.2-4.ppc.rpm");
```

When we issue the above rpm command in the shell prompt, we do not see issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have a buggy %post (well duh! ;-)

Try adding "exit 0" at the end of the %post scriptlet. What appears to be happening is that the return code of the last executed command (i.e. the grep) is being returned to rpm as a failed exit code.

Note that you can pretty easily debug failed package scriptlets (though the technique isn't immediately obvious). Look for rpm-tmp* files in /var/tmp: RPM does not erase expanded scriptlets (i.e. i.e. scripts) when the script fails. You can (usually, not always) debug the script that RPM tried to run using "sh -x" and then propagate the changes back into the *.spec file

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what is wrong with your scriptlet. But you should not modify `/etc/ld.so.conf`. You should just create and distribute file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/%{name}.conf`

Comment: This is not an answer. It is a suggestion and certainly not a fix to the real issue.